# DecodeFile from drawable

Tags: android, image, drawable

i found this function

```
//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
   try {
    //Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

    //The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;

    //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int scale=1;
    while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
        scale*=2;

    //Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize=scale;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
return null;
}
```

my qustion is simple, how can i use this function if my image is from res/drawable?
i use decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.android); but give me outofmemory when i implemented in my app using ViewPager

Comment: The issue may not be with `decodeResource` It maybe in your `getView` method

Answer (score 3):

Just put your BitmanFactory.Options at the end when you decode your bitmap.

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yourbitmap, o2);
```

Comment: It's just the same as in your method except your bitmap is from the /res folder instead.